# Operation timeout error when trying to connect to Amazon Redshift using SQLWorkbench

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have created a cluster in Amazon Redshift Database and have configured security inbound rules. When trying to connect to it using SQLWorkbench client tool I get the following error.

AmazonError setting/closing connection: Operation timed out.

I have one more cluster configured to the same security inbound rules and I can be able to connect to it. Error is specific to this particular cluster.

Please help!!!

Answer (score 7):

Here are most likely causes.

1) Wrong hostname or port

2) `Publicly Accessible` is set "NO" in your Redshift cluster configuration (Only VPC)

If you launched your Redshift cluster in VPC, `Publicly Accessible:` needs to be `YES` to access from outside VPC.

3) VPC security group is not configured correctly

There are two patterns to setup security groups to access Redshift.

- Non-VCP: Redshift Securiy group settings
- VPC: VPC security group settings

I recommend you to check if you setup the correct security group settings along with the place where you launched your Redshift cluster.

If you still cannot solve this issue, it's better to check the following Redshift trouble shooting docs.

[Troubleshooting Connection Issues in Amazon Redshift](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/troubleshooting-connections.html)

Answer (score 0):

Mine got resolved after enabling Redshift cluster "Modify Publicy Accessible setting" in Aws Console

Additional Things to check:-

1. Inbound Security Group Rules attached to the Redshift
2. Whether you have configured driver properly in SQL Workbench i.e "RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.43.1067"

https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-downloads/drivers/jdbc/1.2.43.1067/RedshiftJDBC42-1.2.43.1067.jar

3. Check the JDBC URL, username, password are mentioned properly in SQL Workbench
4. Check for PATH of Java version is "java 11" or not in system environmental variables in your Windows PC

Thanks
Raaz